# Passing variable from makefile to docker compose file?

Tags: linux, docker, makefile, docker-compose

In my docker-compose file, there is more than 3 service. I am passing two-variable from docker command with a makefile. But I'm facing a problem - after executing first command similar second command not executing.

See this example for better understanding-

The docker-compose file is -

```yaml
    version: '3.7'

    services:
         ping:
           container_name: ping_svc
           image: "${PING_IMAGE_NAME}${PING_IMAGE_TAG}" 
           ports:
             - 8080:8080
           command: serve
           environment:
             - CONSUL_URL=consul_dev:8500
             - CONSUL_PATH=ping
           tty: true

         id:
           container_name: id_svc
           image: "${ID_IMAGE_NAME}${ID_IMAGE_TAG}"
           ports:
             - 8081:8081
           command: serve
           environment:
             - CONSUL_URL=consul_dev:8500
             - CONSUL_PATH=id
           tty: true
```

And my makefile command is-

```sh
    # setting ping_image
    @PING_IMAGE_NAME="ping-svc:" PING_IMAGE_TAG="1.0" docker-compose up -d

    # setting id_image
    @ID_IMAGE_NAME="id-svc:" ID_IMAGE_TAG="1.0" docker-compose up -d
```

The `PING_IMAGE_NAME` and `PING_IMAGE_TAG` settings were successfully but from the next line not executing. why?
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: GATEWAY_IMAGE_NAME != ID_IMAGE_NAME

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, edited.

Comment: Maybe create a config file (.env) is a better way: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Yeah, actually I have to pass these variables from command line.

Comment: solved this by putting all variables in 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting all variables in one line.

Like this-

```sh
    @ID_IMAGE_NAME="id-svc:" ID_IMAGE_TAG="1.0" \
    PING_IMAGE_NAME="ping-svc:" PING_IMAGE_TAG="1.0" \
    docker-compose up -d  ping  id
```

Here `ping` and `id` is my container name.

Maybe the issue was every time I'm upping docker-compose.